# int * int vs (int * int) in OCaml sum type

Tags: ocaml

```
type foo = A of int * int | B of (int * int)
```

What is the difference between `int * int` and `(int * int)` there? The only difference I see is in pattern matching:

```
let test_foo = function
  | A (f, s) -> (f, s)
  | B b -> b
```

Is it just a syntactic sugar? How do you select which one to use? Is there any performance difference between these two forms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a performance difference:

In memory `A (23, 42)` will contain a tag identifying it as an `A` and the two integers 23 and 42. `B (23, 42)` will contain a tag identifying it as a `B` and a pointer to a tuple containing the integers `23` and `42`. So there will be one additional memory allocation when creating a `B` and one additional level of indirection when accessing the individual values inside a `B`. So in cases where you don't actually use the constructor arguments as a tuple, using `A` will involve less overhead than using `B`.

On the other hand your `test_foo` function will create a new tuple every time it is called with an `A` value, but when it is called with a `B` value it will simply return the tuple that already exists in memory. So `test_foo` is a cheaper operation for `B` than it is for `A`. So if you'll be using the constructor's arguments as a tuple and you will do so multiple times for the same value, using `B` will be cheaper.

So if you're going to be using the constructor arguments as a tuple, it makes sense to use a constructor taking a tuple because you can get at the tuple using pattern matching with less code and because it will avoid having to create tuples from the same value multiple times. In all other cases not using a tuple is preferable because it involves less memory allocation and less indirection.

Comment: So, it is not possible to extract info from `A` without new tuple creation, right?

Comment: @Stas That depends on what you mean by "extract info". It is not possible to get a tuple containing an `A`'s data without creating a new tuple. But it's certainly possible to do something with an `A`'s data without creating a tuple. For example something like `match foo with A (x, y) -> x+y` will not create a tuple and will be faster than the equivalent code using `B`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks! I thought tuple is needed to match `A (x,y)`.

Comment: If I do `A (23,42)`, there is no tuple created, right?

Answer (score 2):

As already said, the constructor of `A` takes two `int`, whereas the constructor of `B` takes an ordered pair.

so you can write

```
let bar = A (1, 2)
```

or

```
let bar = B (1, 2)
```

or

```
let bar = (1, 2)
let baz = B bar
```

but you cannot write

```
let bar = (1, 2)
let baz = A bar
```

Moreover, in your pattern matching, you can still match the content of B as two int, but you cannot match the content of A as value bound to an ordered pair

```
let test_foo = function
  | A a -> a (* wrong *)
  | B (f, s) -> (f, s) (* ok *)
```

Answer (score 0):

They are two different types. The interpretation of this syntax is ambiguous at the `*` operator. It may be reduced into the form:

`type x = Y * Z` in which the '*' is associated with the `type` keyword in OCaml
or
`int * int` in which the `*` is used in the capacity of an operator that constructs a tuple

The default precedence takes it to the former. By putting a parenthesis around the `(int * int)` you override the default precedence and force the latter interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the tricky things in OCaml syntax -- even though it looks like you are declaring a constructor with a tuple data type (`A of int * int`), and even though when you use the constructor, it looks like you are giving a tuple to it (`A (2,3)`), that is not actually what is happening.

If you actually construct a tuple value and try to pass it to the constructor, it will not compile -- `let x = (2,3) in A x`. Rather, the `*` in the constructor definition and the `(,)` in the constructor use expression are simply the syntax for a constructor of *multiple arguments*. The syntax imitates that of a constructor with a tuple argument, but is actually separate. The extra parentheses are necessary if you want to actually make a constructor with a single tuple argument.