# Best way to represent a file/folder structure

Tags: data-structures, ocaml

I want to represent a file structure to later write it to disk. What I need is to have a way to represent files, folders, their relationships and their contents. For example, represent a file structure like this:

```
|-one.txt -> contains "This is file 1"
|-aFolder
| |-aNestedFolder
| | |-aDoublyNestedEmptyFolder
|-anotherFolder
| |-aNestedFile -> contains "Contents of aNestedFile"
|-yetAnotherEmptyFolder
```

I am using this right now:

```
type fileTree =
  | File of (string * string)
  | Folder of (string * (fileTree list))

let example = [
  File ("one.txt", "This is file 1");
  Folder ("aFolder", 
      [Folder ("aNestedFolder", 
          [Folder ("aDoublyNestedEmptyFolder", [])])]) ;
  Folder ("anotherFolder", 
      [File ("aNestedFile", "Contents of aNestedFile")]);
  Folder ("yetAnotherEmptyFolder", []);
]
```

This works for now, but I'd like to know if there's a smarter way to represent a file structure like this.

Answer (score 3):

Your representation is completely straightforward, so it's hard to think of a better one unless you have more specific requirements.

A tiny (more or less cosmetic) change would be to use:

```
type fileTree =
  | File of string * string
  | Folder of string * fileTree list
```

This isn't the same type, and is a tiny bit more effective when you don't need a direct representation of the pairs.

If you want to look files up quickly in this kind of structure, and if the structure is going to get really large, you might want to use nested maps or hashtables.

**Update**

There's some discussion of the difference between the two types. It has been explained very well before here at SO, but I haven't been able to find the page. Here's a session showing the difference:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

# type f = A of (int * int);;
type f = A of (int * int)
# type g = B of int * int;;
type g = B of int * int
# let x = (8, 7);;
val x : int * int = (8, 7)
# A x;;
- : f = A (8, 7)
# B x;;
Error: The constructor B expects 2 argument(s),
       but is applied here to 1 argument(s)
#
```

The `A` constructor takes one value, a pair of ints. The `B` constructor takes two separate int values, not a pair.

In memory, a value of type `f` will have a header and one field. The one field will point to a pair (a header and two fields). A value of type `g` will just have a header and two fields.

It's not a big deal, mostly it's just interesting (at least to me).

**Update 2**

Here's a good SO discussion of this issue:

> [int * int vs (int * int) in OCaml sum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818866/int-int-vs-int-int-in-ocaml-sum-type)

Comment: Could you please explain in which ways your type is different and a bit more effective?

Comment: In essence `File of (string * string)` has one field that's a pair while `File of string * string` has two separate fields. It takes a tiny bit longer to retrieve an element from the pair because there's one extra indirection.

Comment: I have experiment with the toplevel and there is no indication of what you describe:

Comment: After the type declaration `type t = X of int * string` the evaluation of the expression `X 2 "abc"` fails with a syntax error, but `X (2, "ana")` succeeds. Similarly `match X 2 "ana" with X p _ -> p` fails with a syntax error and `match X (2, "ana") with X (p, _) -> p` succeeds. This demonstrates that `X` should have a *pair* as argument, and not to separate arguments.

Comment: Handling of constructor arguments is a little tricky in OCaml. The parentheses are optional if the constructor takes just one value. Hence the surface syntax looks the same for the two cases. This is why it's a strange corner of the language.

Comment: What puzzles me is the different treatment that a tuple value expression is been given. `let arg = (2, "aaa") in arg` should be the same as `(2, "aaa")`, but this examples shows it is not when constructing variant type values. There should be another syntax for that, probably.